# Powermock not mocking for Consul class

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito, powermock, powermockito

This is a class method I want to test and I want to mock all Consul calls.
But whenever I run as junit test I get NullPointerException error for Consul builder. It did not create a mock connection for Consul.class .Can any one help me.

```
public Dependency checkConsulHealth(String consulUrl, String aclToken) {
    try {
        Consul.builder().withUrl(consulUrl).withAclToken(aclToken).build();
        LOGGER.debug("Consul connection successful");
        return new Dependency(consulUrl, CONSUL_SERVICE, SUCCESS_MESSAGE, SUCCESS_STATUS);
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        LOGGER.debug("Consul connection unsuccessful");
        return new Dependency(consulUrl, CONSUL_SERVICE, ERROR_MESSAGE, ERROR_STATUS);
    }
}
```

This is my test class here I am trying to test my healthCheckService class method.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(fullyQualifiedNames = "com.orbitz.consul.Consul")
public class TestHealthCheckService {

    private static final String CONSUL_URL = "Consul";
    private static final String ACL_TOKEN = "123";

    @InjectMocks
    private HealthCheckService healthCheckService;

@Before
public void init() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(Consul.class);
}


@Test
public void testCheckConsulHealth() {

    PowerMockito.mockStatic(Consul.class);
    Dependency dependency1 = new Dependency(CONSUL_URL, CONSUL_SERVICE, SUCCESS_MESSAGE, 
         SUCCESS_STATUS);
    System.out.println("From mock "+Consul.builder());
    PowerMockito.when(Consul.builder()
                            .withUrl(CONSUL_URL)
                            .withAclToken(ACL_TOKEN)
                            .build())
                            .thenReturn(null);
    Dependency dependency2 = healthCheckService.checkConsulHealth(CONSUL_URL, ACL_TOKEN);
    assertEquals(dependency1, dependency2);
}
```

My POM.xml dependency is where I used following dependecies

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.powermock/powermock-api-mockito2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.powermock/powermock-module-junit4 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't use and don't know Consul client, but your problem isn't related to your dependencies: basically you have to mock all steps.

Please take the following example (about a builder pattern) only as suggestion and adapt it to your case replacing Mock, as and where you need, with PowerMockito:

```
Foo f = mock(Foo.class);
FooBuilder b = mock(FooBuilder.class);
when(b.enableAlpha()).thenReturn(b);
when(b.disableBeta()).thenReturn(b);
when(b.increaseGamma()).thenReturn(b);
when(b.build()).thenReturn(f);
```

Comment: Tried with this , but mockStatic method is not creating mock object for Consul.